# Error with App Store Update on iPhone 6 and iPad Pro

Tags: applications, software-update, error

I have never heard of or installed this Numbo Call Blocker app, but my Update screen wants to update it anyway. It fails when it tries. I searched on the App store and did not find it. It looks suspicious to me. 
Is there a way I can delete it from the update list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

search your device for ‘call” and you should see it.   the version you have will not appear in a search for ‘numbo’.

i don’t know a way to ‘go to’ an app in the iOS finder but hunt in the usual way looking for the icon.  the app is simply called ‘call blocker’.   it’s there, when you find it just dispose of it in then usual way,  a long press on the icon and then tap the ‘x’ that appears when it starts to wiggle.

cw